# Visualizing call tree for a request .NET

Tags: .net

I've got a web application which works in a similar way to .NET MVC. It has a custom HttpModule which captures requests and then sends them off to my application which does it's own thing and writes to the response.

What I'd like to be able to do is track the route a request takes through my code and visualize it in some kind of hierarchy. For example,

```
-- RequestBroker.ProcessRequest
---- SomeClass.Method
---- AnotherClass.Method
------ ThirdClass.Utility
------ ThirdClass.Utility
------ ThirdClass.Utility
---- SomeClass.Method2
---- SomeClass.Method3
```

etc. etc.

Are there any tools out there that could help me with this? I'm not so much looking to profile the slowest methods but more to find out the route a request takes to determine any thing strange going on.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Isn't normal debugging combined with logging enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a ready made tool but there are various ways this can be achieved:

1. If you are using DI, some tools such as Windsor Castle allow for tracing of all methods called
2. Some Aspect Oriented tools such as PostSharp can help to add tracing for calls

Above only applies for methods of classes you own.

If you need to do that including classes you do not own, listen to this [Podcast](http://deepfriedbytes.com/podcast/episode-76-il-rewriting-and-what-net-assemblies-look-like-under-the-microscope-with-philip-laureano/).

Answer (score 0):

checkout Mono Cecil.

http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil:FAQ